# writing and pronouncing Bible references

Tags: bible

How would you say this Bible reference:  Malachi 3:7b,8 & 10,11?
Also, is it written correctly?

Answer (score 2):

I generally use “through” (spoken) or a hyphen (written) for any adjacent verses, and “and” (spoken) or a comma (written) to signify a jump in verses.

Malachi 3:7b-8, 10-11

Malachi three seven bee through eight and ten through eleven.

Or

Malachi chapter three verses seven bee through eight and ten through eleven.

Answer (score 1):

As [bruised reed has demonstrated](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/71819/1377), generally when you're reading a reference you just read what it says.

If you were using this to **announce a reading,** then there are a few ways:

- In Roman Catholic liturgy the details aren't necessary

  > A reading from the prophet Malachi
- In Church of England liturgy, in traditional language the reference is read in “reverse order”

  > Here beginneth the seventh verse of the third chapter of the book of the prophet Malachi
- Other liturgies

  There may be no set way. I’ve certainly heard “The first lesson comes from Malachi chapter three, starting to read from the second part of verse seven”

Answer (score 0):

There are two popular ways to express in notation those collection of verses:

1. Grouped by passages:

   Malachi 3:7b-8 & 10-11

   pronunciation: *MAL-ah-kai* chapter three verses seven *bee* to eight and ten to eleven.
2. List of verses:

   Malachi 3:7b,8,10&11

   pronunciation: *MAL-ah-kai* chapter three verses seven *bee*,eight,ten and eleven.

Comment: Also Malachi 3:7b-8, 10-11. For any format I'd add a space after all commas.